# Angular2: losing access to an observable

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have an ionic/angular2 app running. There is a google map that is loaded into view. I have an observable called `markers` which is an array of google maps marker objects. I push them to the array to get them to appear on the map. I then add event listeners to all of the markers. The clicking is functional, however, I lose access to `this.markers`. Why does this happen? Maybe a better question is how can I create a plain variable that is accessible throughout the class?

Here is my code:

```
 export class MapView
 { 
   markers: any;

   ngOnInit()
   {
     //initialization for map and the raw marker array data not shown
     this.addListeners()
   }

   addListeners() //functions properly (this.markers is accessible)
   {
     console.log(this.markers) //displays the markers array properly
     for(var i = 0; i < this.markers.length; i++)
     {
       this.markers[i].addListener("click",this.markerClicked, this);
     }
   }

   markerClicked(marker) //the clicked marker is passed
   {
     console.log(this.markers);
     //here is the problem. The console says that the markers array is empty
     //when called from this function
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's because when your callback `this.markerClicked` is called, it is no longer bound to the class, therefore `this.markers` is no longer accessible.

I see two options:

1) Inline your callback and declare it using an arrow function (arrow functions preserve the context of `this`)

```
this.markers[i].addListener("click", (marker) => {
  // do something with marker and this.markers
  console.log(this.markers);
}, this);
```

2) Seems a bit hackish but... Have you tried binding your callback to the class?

Something like `this.markerClicked.bind(this)` instead of just `this.markerClicked`.

Comment: That worked perfectly! One more additional question: is there any way that I can figure out which one of the markers from the array was actually clicked? I was trying to pass the `i` index to the arrow function, but I couldn't get that to work. Any other ideas?

Comment: If you want to stay inline with the GMaps API, you have to attach another event listener to the marker itself, i.e. `marker.addListener('click', () => { ... })`. Then, you can reuse the `marker` variable from within the arrow function if you need.